# Cakephp - How to make model accept changes made in phpmyadmin?

Tags: cakephp, caching, save

I have added one more field in db table and have added validation rule for it in model class. But on saving the record all data get saved except that new field (note: validation for new field works). That field is not there in the model object schema attribute. Have cleared the cache directory and then on saving new record, got new cache created with this new field but got 'internal server error' instead of successful insertion. May I kindly know, where exactly the issue lies.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please follow the below steps:

Step 1: Change debug status in app/config/core.php

```
Configure::write('debug', 3);
```

Step 2: Run your code/script again.

It will solve your problem.

Note: make sure you have added the required field in db table.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by setting Configure::write('debug', 1); in app/config/core.php. Earlier its 0 that didn't get latest model status where 1 get the updated status of db.